# observeValueForKeyPath not being called

Tags: iphone, key-value-observing

I have a ViewController creating an instance of a UIView, and then I register an observer with the instance, such that

```
logoAnimation = [[MainLogoAnimation alloc] init];
[logoAnimation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"patrocinioDidLoad" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
```

then, in the same file, I have:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
 NSLog(@"%@ \n %@ \n %@ \n ",keyPath,object,change);
}
```

But, although I have checked and double-checked that logoAnimation.patrocinioDidLoad has changed, observeValueForKeyPath never gets called...

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Antonio

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved it:
I was setting patrocinioDidLoad in logoAnimation directly, without using standard getters and setters. In logoAnimation,

```
patrocinioDidLoad = YES;
```

didn't work, whereas

```
self.patrocinioDidLoad = YES;
```

did!

Comment: thanks you solved my problem

For me, something like logoAnimation = [[MainLogoAnimation alloc] init]; didn't work but self.logoAnimation = [[MainLogoAnimation alloc] init]autorelease]; works.

Comment: So you always have to put "self" in front if you want to use the setters and getters made by @synthesize?

Comment: WOW! After hours of testing my code to find why obserValueForKeyPath wasn't ever being called, I finally found that this was why. Why doesn't Apple bold it in the docs that one must go through the setter (and thus use the property instead of the ivar) for it to work?